# Tempus Dominus Bootstrap4 requires moment.js. (datetime picker)

Tags: javascript, jquery, webpack, momentjs, laravel-mix

I am trying to add a DateTimePicker using Tempus Dominus Bootstrap4. But I am getting the following error.

[image: console screenshot]
I use Laravel as a front-end. So I use laravel-mix.

my blade file is below

```
@extends('layouts.app')


@section('content')
@if((Auth::user()->hasRole('teacher')) || (Auth::user()->hasRole('admin')) || (Auth::user()->hasRole('superadmin')) )
<div class="container">
    <div class="row justify-content-center">
        <div class="col-md-8">
            <div class="card">
                <div class="card-header">{{__("Dashboard")}}</div>

                <div class="card-body">
                    <p>{{ Auth::user()->name }}</p>
                    <p>{{ $errors->first('JSONerror') }}</p>   
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-6">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <div class="input-group date" id="datetimepicker1" data-target-input="nearest">
                        <input type="text" class="form-control datetimepicker-input" data-target="#datetimepicker1"/>
                        <div class="input-group-append" data-target="#datetimepicker1" data-toggle="datetimepicker">
                            <div class="input-group-text"><i class="fa fa-calendar"></i></div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <script type="text/javascript">
                $(function () {
                    $('#datetimepicker1').datetimepicker();
                });
            </script>
        </div>
    </div>
@else
<div class="container">
        <div class="row justify-content-center">
            <div class="col-md-8">
                <div class="card">
                    <div class="card-header">Authority Problem</div>
                    <div class="card-body">
                        {{__("You do not have the authority to reach this page")}}
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
@endif
@endsection
```

my layouts.app blade file is:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="{{ app()->getLocale() }}">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

    <!-- CSRF Token -->
    <meta name="csrf-token" content="{{ csrf_token() }}">

    <title>{{ config('app.name', 'Laravel') }}</title>

    <!-- Scripts -->
    <script src="{{ asset('js/app.js') }}" defer></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <!-- Fonts -->
    <link rel="dns-prefetch" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Raleway:300,400,600" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">

    <!-- Styles -->
    <link href="{{ asset('css/app.css') }}" rel="stylesheet">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ asset('css/fullcalendar.css') }}">
</head>
<body>
    <div id="app">
        <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-md navbar-light navbar-laravel">
            <div class="container">
                <a class="navbar-brand" href="{{ url('/') }}">
                    {{ config('app.name', 'Laravel') }}
                </a>
                <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
                    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
                </button>

                <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
                    <!-- Left Side Of Navbar -->
                    <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">

                    </ul>

                    <!-- Right Side Of Navbar -->
                    <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
                        <!-- Authentication Links -->
                        @guest
                            <li><a class="nav-link" href="{{ route('login') }}">{{ __('Login') }}</a></li>
                            <li><a class="nav-link" href="{{ route('register') }}">{{ __('Register') }}</a></li>
                        @else
                            <li class="nav-item dropdown">
                                <a id="navbarDropdown" class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false" v-pre>
                                    {{ Auth::user()->name }} <span class="caret"></span>
                                </a>

                                <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">
                                    <a class="dropdown-item" href="{{ route('logout') }}"
                                       onclick="event.preventDefault();
                                                     document.getElementById('logout-form').submit();">
                                        {{ __('Logout') }}
                                    </a>

                                    <form id="logout-form" action="{{ route('logout') }}" method="POST" style="display: none;">
                                        @csrf
                                    </form>
                                </div>
                            </li>
                        @endguest
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        </nav>

        <main class="py-4">
            @yield('content')
        </main>
    </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

my app.js file:

```
    /**
 * First we will load all of this project's JavaScript dependencies which
 * includes Vue and other libraries. It is a great starting point when
 * building robust, powerful web applications using Vue and Laravel.
 */

require('./bootstrap');

window.Vue = require('vue');

/**
 * Next, we will create a fresh Vue application instance and attach it to
 * the page. Then, you may begin adding components to this application
 * or customize the JavaScript scaffolding to fit your unique needs.
 */

Vue.component('example-component', require('./components/ExampleComponent.vue'));

const app = new Vue({
    el: '#app'
});
Vue.config.devtools = true;

$.ajaxSetup({
    headers: {
        'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
    }
});
```

my bootstrap.js file:

```
window._ = require('lodash');
window.Popper = require('popper.js').default;

/**
 * We'll load jQuery and the Bootstrap jQuery plugin which provides support
 * for JavaScript based Bootstrap features such as modals and tabs. This
 * code may be modified to fit the specific needs of your application.
 */

try {
    window.$ = window.jQuery = require('jquery');

    require('bootstrap');
} catch (e) {
    alert("JQ is not loaded");
}

/**
 * We'll load the axios HTTP library which allows us to easily issue requests
 * to our Laravel back-end. This library automatically handles sending the
 * CSRF token as a header based on the value of the "XSRF" token cookie.
 */

window.axios = require('axios');

window.axios.defaults.headers.common['X-Requested-With'] = 'XMLHttpRequest';

/**
 * Next we will register the CSRF Token as a common header with Axios so that
 * all outgoing HTTP requests automatically have it attached. This is just
 * a simple convenience so we don't have to attach every token manually.
 */

let token = document.head.querySelector('meta[name="csrf-token"]');

if (token) {
    window.axios.defaults.headers.common['X-CSRF-TOKEN'] = token.content;
} else {
    console.error('CSRF token not found: https://laravel.com/docs/csrf#csrf-x-csrf-token');
}

/**
 * Echo exposes an expressive API for subscribing to channels and listening
 * for events that are broadcast by Laravel. Echo and event broadcasting
 * allows your team to easily build robust real-time web applications.
 */

// import Echo from 'laravel-echo'

// window.Pusher = require('pusher-js');

// window.Echo = new Echo({
//     broadcaster: 'pusher',
//     key: process.env.MIX_PUSHER_APP_KEY,
//     cluster: process.env.MIX_PUSHER_APP_CLUSTER,
//     encrypted: true
// });


/* 
*For fullcalendar and reservation
*/
//import $ from 'jquery';
import 'moment';
import 'fullcalendar';
import 'tempusdominus-bootstrap-4';
import 'moment-timezone';
```

The package.json file is like below.

```
    {
    "private": true,
    "scripts": {
        "dev": "npm run development",
        "development": "cross-env NODE_ENV=development node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js --progress --hide-modules --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js",
        "watch": "npm run development -- --watch",
        "watch-poll": "npm run watch -- --watch-poll",
        "hot": "cross-env NODE_ENV=development node_modules/webpack-dev-server/bin/webpack-dev-server.js --inline --hot --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js",
        "prod": "npm run production",
        "production": "cross-env NODE_ENV=production node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js --no-progress --hide-modules --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js"
    },
    "devDependencies": {
        "axios": "^0.18",
        "bootstrap": "^4.0.0",
        "cross-env": "^5.1",
        "jquery": "^3.3.1",
        "laravel-mix": "^2.0",
        "lodash": "^4.17.4",
        "popper.js": "^1.12",
        "vue": "^2.5.7"
    },
    "dependencies": {
        "fullcalendar": "^3.9.0",
        "moment": "^2.21.0",
        "moment-timezone": "^0.5.14",
        "tempusdominus-bootstrap-4": "^5.0.0-alpha18"
    }
}
```

Can you help me. I spent a lot of time with this problem.

Comment: There are nobody knows answer? I can give him 10 bucks :)

Answer (score 20, accepted):

I changed bootstrap.js and it works.

```js
global.moment = require('moment');
require('tempusdominus-bootstrap-4');
import 'fullcalendar';
import 'moment-timezone';
```

Comment: This worked for me but rather than edit `bootstrap.js`, which could change with Laravel updates, I put these lines in `app.js` directly after the call to bootstrap.

Answer (score 0):

To solve this I added moment to the webpack.ProvidePlugin in webpack.config.js

```
plugins: [
    new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
      $: 'jquery',
      jQuery: 'jquery',
      'window.jQuery': 'jquery',
      moment: 'moment'
    })
  ]
```

Answer (score 0):

For me just down moment js plucgin and include file to page you use datepicker